# Issue with Date_SUB And BETWEEN function

Tags: google-bigquery

I came across this issue while creating a parametrised query; Then intent of the query is to pull past 5 months (excluding current month) data based on the date passed as a variable. Basic table schema for **Table A** is as follows:

```
as_of_date  Y   X
2019-12-31  1   AB
2019-11-30  2   CD
2019-10-31  3   EF 
2019-09-30  4   GH
2019-08-31  5   MN
2019-07-31  6   XYZ
2020-01-31  7   PQR
2020-02-29  8   AAA
```

Following is the query I wrote:

```
WITH
date
AS
(
SELECT CAST("2020-02-29" AS Date) as run_date
)

SELECT DISTINCT CAST(a.as_of_date AS DATE) as_of_date,
FROM  A as a
WHERE CAST(a.as_of_date AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB((SELECT run_date FROM date), INTERVAL 5 Month) AND DATE_SUB((SELECT run_date FROM date), INTERVAL 1 Month)
```

This query runs fine when run_date is set to "2020-01-31" and returns past 5 months data i.e. Dec, Nov, October, Sept, and August. But fails when date is set to "2020-02-29" it only returns 4 months data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple "fix" is to add `DATE_TRUNC(..., MONTH)` as in below example

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(a.as_of_date AS DATE) as_of_date,
FROM `project.dataset.tableA` AS a
WHERE DATE_TRUNC(CAST(a.as_of_date AS DATE), MONTH) 
  BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB((SELECT run_date FROM date_cte), INTERVAL 5 Month), MONTH) 
      AND DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB((SELECT run_date FROM date_cte), INTERVAL 1 Month), MONTH)
```

Comment: glad it worked for you. please consider also voting up the answer